# Safari does not send ice candidates

Tags: safari, webrtc, kurento

don't work example in safari

https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-one2many-call

In chrome, everything is fine.

Safary does not send ice candidates in view mode. Presenter mode is ok

====================

## update

**In the Front (index.js)**

The event onOfferViewer is  always executed

onIceCandidate – never executed

**Connection from Front to the node**

var ws = new WebSocket('wss://' + location.host + '/one2many');

On KMS a Turn doesn’t  turn on, but a Stun is configured. I can broadcasting from Safari, but I cannot watching on it

**Look at kurento utils  deeper**

2 Sturm servers are chosen, before WebRtcPeer initialization

*iceServers: Array (2)* 
*0 {username: undefined, credential: undefined, url:* *"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302", urls: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}*

*1 {username: undefined, credential: undefined, url:* *"stun:stun.voipbuster.com", urls: ["stun:stun.voipbuster.com"]}*

After RTCPeerConnection is created
After Process answer is executed

**I think the next step has to be in a function addEventListener**

```js
pc.addEventListener('icecandidate', function (event) {…}
```

In Chrome in the function addEventListener a callback is executed  but for Safari never.

I can assume that the candidates come before the subscription is taking place, but there is no evidence, and I don’t  understand why the presenter works fine.

## detail

I started broadcasting in the presenter mode in the Safari

**The Safari version** -  13604.3.5 (MacOs  - 11.0.1)

**The Safari options**

Old api - Enabled

Ice restrictions - Disabled

**The Bower’s dependencies**

```
"dependencies": { 
    "adapter.js": "v0.2.9", 
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.0", 
    "ekko-lightbox": "~3.3.0", 
    "demo-console": "1.5.1", 
    "kurento-utils": "master" 
 }
```

**The package.json structure**

```
{ 
  "name": "kurento-one2many-call", 
  "version": "6.7.3-dev", 
  "private": true, 
  "scripts": { 
    "postinstall": "cd static && bower install" 
  }, 
  "dependencies": { 
    "express": "~4.12.4", 
    "minimist": "^1.1.1", 
    "ws": "~1.0.1", 
    "kurento-client": "Kurento/kurento-client-js" 
  }, 
  "devDependencies": { 
    "bower": "^1.4.1" 
  } 
}
```

**Output of Safari logs**

Output of Safari logs

```
[Log] Browser does not appear to be WebRTC-capable (adapter.js, line 34) 

[Debug] constraints: {"offerToReceiveAudio":true,"offerToReceiveVideo":true} (kurento-utils.js, line 268) 

[Debug] Created SDP offer (kurento-utils.js, line 270) 

[Debug] Local description set – "v=0 

↵o=- 5811275597248577793 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 

↵s=- 

↵t=0 0 

↵a=msid-semantic: WMS 

↵" (kurento-utils.js, line 275) 

"v=0 

o=- 5811275597248577793 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 

s=- 

t=0 0 

a=msid-semantic: WMS 

" 

[Log] Senging message: {"id":"viewer","sdpOffer":"v=0\r\no=- 5811275597248577793 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\n"} (index.js, line 70) 

[Info] Received message: {"id":"viewerResponse","response":"accepted","sdpAnswer":"v=0\r\no=- 3748169328 3748169328 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=Kurento Media Server\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\n"} (index.js, line 70) 

[Debug] SDP answer received, setting remote description (kurento-utils.js, line 320)  

[Debug] Remote stream: – undefined (kurento-utils.js, line 294)
```

**How to a node connects to KMS**

```
var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
    default: { 
        as_uri: 'https://localhost:8443/',      
        ws_uri: 'ws://37.228.89.170:8888/kurento' 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

1. Safari 12 only - Need to enable the experimental feature "Enable MDNS Ice Candidates" in Safari settings, advanced, experimental features
2. Safari 11 - you have to call `getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})`, and have the user accept the dialog box to allow video and audio on your page. Even though you don't want to use the video or audio, this then causes safari to send ice-candidates during the negotiation

Answer (score -1):

This question is vague and does not provide a lot of detail. Please provide more details on the issue you are experiencing and what you have done to try to fix it/debug it.

You might try to disable the ICE candidate restrictions option in the developer menu and restart Safari, as mentioned [in this Google Group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meetecho-janus/drunykSJEPU). Without knowing more information, I can't help much more than this.

For the future, please provide more thorough and detailed information on the problem and solutions you have attempted.

Comment: description added